# NLTK Lookup Error for punkt downloading on pyspark dataframe in Databricks

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, nltk, databricks

I am trying to find the similarities of text columns('title', 'headline') by applying cosine similarity to the pyspark dataframe in Databricks. My function is called 'cosine_sim_udf' and to able to use it, I have to do the first udf conversion.

I get lookup error after applying the function to df. Does anyone know a reason or have a solution suggestion?

My function to find cosine similarities;

```
nltk.download('punkt')

stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]


'''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return float(((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1])
```

```
cosine_sim_udf = udf(cosine_sim, FloatType())

df2 =  df.withColumn('cosine_distance', cosine_sim_udf('title', 'headline')) # title and headline are text to find similarities
```

then I get this error;

```
PythonException: 'LookupError: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 426.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 426.0 (TID 2135) (10.109.245.129 executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  [0m
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load [93mtokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle[0m

  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/databricks/python/nltk_data'
    - '/databricks/python/share/nltk_data'
    - '/databricks/python/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your case the `nltk.download('punkt')` was executed only on the driver node, while your UDF function is executed on the worker nodes, where it's not installed.

You have following possibilities:

- install required resource using [cluster init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) with something like this (it will install this file on all nodes):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pip install nltk
python -m nltk.downloader punkt
```

- Something like this (haven't tested, but may work. Also may not work on the autoscaling cluster):

```py
import nltk
num_executors = sc._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus().size()-1
sc.parallelize((("")*num_executors), num_executors) \
  .mapPartitions(lambda p: [nltk.download('punkt')]).collect()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have tried init script way but having this error when i start the cluster unfortunately.

Message
Cluster terminated.Reason:Init script failure

Cluster scoped init script dbfs:/databricks/scripts/punkt-install.sh failed: Script exit status is non-zero

Comment: I forgot to add `pip install nltk` into that init script

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer is tested on DataBricks version running on 2023-08. User interfaces tend to change over time, so always check the docs:

https://docs.databricks.com/en/libraries/workspace-libraries.html

quoting:
"Workspace libraries serve as a local repository from which you create cluster-installed libraries.
...
You must install a workspace library on a cluster before it can be used in a notebook or job"

In Databricks, you install a library to a cluster (for your own use), or install in the workspace to make it available to all clusters in the workspace.

The library can be for example a python lib (nltk) from pypi, a JAR file you built etc.

To recap what the docs say:
To install in one cluster:

- In your workspace, choose "Compute" in the left window.
- choose "Libraries" tab.
- click the "Install now" button.
- For your case, choose "library source" Pypi, "package" nltk [ I don't know why, but when I specified 'nltk==3.8.1' the installation seemed to fail]. They DO recommend to use a specific version.
- restart the cluster
- try it:

  ```
  import nltk
  nltk.download('punkt')
  ```

To install in the Workspace:

- click "workspace"
- choose the workspace you want to install. e.g. "shared"
- right click , Create, Library

Now the library is available to clusters the next time they restart.

Comment: it won't work because `nltk.download('punkt')` will be executed only on a driver node, not on the executors