# Error installing en_core_web_sm in Databricks when used in ADF pipeline

Tags: databricks, spacy, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I tried to create an install script

```
spacy.sh
#!/bin/bash

pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

as given in the answer for [Error while importing 'en_core_web_sm' for spacy in Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72307171/error-while-importing-en-core-web-sm-for-spacy-in-azure-databricks) by @AlexOTTt

as

```
   dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/Filestore/scripts/")
   dbutils.fs.put("/Filestore/scripts/spacy.sh", """
   #!/bin/bash
   pip install spacy
   python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm""", True)
```

in the folder dbfs:/Filestore/scripts

But I got the error

```
  OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from 
 /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/config.cfg
```

Please let me know how to fix this error

Comment: That error looks like what you get if you try to load a spaCy v2 model with v3. Check your spaCy versions and be sure you aren't running v3 anywhere. Your model's version number should start with a 3.

Comment: I added these 3 lines and I still get the issue.   #!/bin/bash

pip install spacy
#python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm 
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz